# Appending alpine js variable to laravel blade component's attribute

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm trying to append the value inside the alpine JS variable to Laravel blade component's attribute

I'm using laravel 10, Alpine V3 and Livewire V3
Here's my code :

```
<template x-for="(field, index) in fields" :key="index">
    <tr>
        <td x-text="index+1"></td>
        <td>
            <x-forms.input wire:model="journals.index.account" type="text"></x-forms.input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <x-forms.input wire:model="journals.index.amount" type="text"></x-forms.input>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" @click="removeField(index)">&times;</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

The x-forms.input component :

```
<div>
    <input
        type="{{ $type }}"
        class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500">
</div>
```

And here's my alpine code :

```
<script>
    function handler () {
        return {
          fields: [],
          addNewField() {
              this.fields.push({
                  txt1: '',
                  txt2: ''
               });
            },
            removeField(index) {
               this.fields.splice(index, 1);
             }
          }
    }
</script>
```

My Livewire class :

```
class CreateJournal extends Component
{
    public $journals = [];

    public function save()
    {
        foreach ($this->journals as $journal) {
            \App\Models\Payable::create($journal);
        }
    }
}
```

The intended result is to append the **index** variable of alpine to the blade wire:model attribute like so :

```
<x-forms.input model="journals.**index**.account" type="text"></x-forms.input>
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that *wire:model* is evaluated before Alpine objects are instantiated, so it can't interact with Alpine's variables.

We could use *@entangle* to use an Alpine variable that references a Livewire variable, but since version 3 of Livewire it is possible to use the magic property *$wire* to directly reference the Livewire component, so we can use this feature.

From your example the relationship between the Livewire *journals* property and the Alpine *fields[]* property is not very clear, I will assume that they refer to the same data and therefore I will do without *fields[]*.
I also assumed that your *addNewField()* and *removeField()* will handle rows, not fields (this was a bit cryptic)

The Livewire class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TheClass extends Component
{
    // these are example data

    public $journals = [

        ['account' => 'acc001', 'amount' => 10] ,
        ['account' => 'acc002', 'amount' => 20]
    ];
}
```

The view:

```html
<div x-data="handler">

    <table>

        <template x-for="(row, index) in $wire.journals" :key="row.rowKey">

            <tr>

                <td x-text="index + 1"></td>

                <td>
                    <x-forms.input x-model="row.account" type="text" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <x-forms.input x-model="row.amount" type="text" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" 
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-small"
                            @click="removeRow(index)"
                    >
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </td>


            </tr>

        </template>

    </table>

    <br>

    <button @click="addNewRow()">
        [ADD ROW]
    </button>

    <button @click="$wire.$refresh">
        [REFRESH]
    </button>

    <br>
    <br>
 
    // the foreach is for debugging 

    @foreach($journals as $row)

        @php($rowId = $row['rowKey'] ?? ' ')

        <div>
            {{ "($rowId) - ({$row['account']}) - ({$row['amount']})" }}
        </div>

    @endforeach

    <script>

        function handler () {

            return {

                init() {
                    let rowKey = Date.now();
                    this.$wire.journals.forEach (el => {typeof el.rowKey == "undefined"  &&  (el.rowKey = rowKey++)});
                },

                addNewRow() {

                    this.$wire.journals.push ({

                        account: '',
                        amount: '',
                        rowKey: Date.now()
                    });
                },

                removeRow(index) {
                    this.$wire.journals.splice (index, 1);
                }
            }
        }

    </script>

</div>
```

In the *x-for* loop I referenced the *journals* property via *$wire*.

I also added to each row a *"unique"* key (in the *init()* and *addNewRow()* methods) to use as *:key* because when a row is deleted using *splice()*, the indexes are compacted and this can confuse *x-for*. Consider whether to modify this functionality and for example manage the key in the backend (you can use an *id* if it already exists).

I also inserted a *@foreach* for debugging purposes only: by clicking on the *REFRESH* button the data is sent to the backend and the component is updated accordingly, showing the changes.

### Edit

Here a working version of the *input* Blade component:

```html
<div>
    <input {{ $attributes->merge([
                'class' => 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg ' .
                           'focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 ' .
                           'dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 ' .
                           'dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500'
              ])
           }}
    >
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solutions, but after i hit the save button those data (input value of account & amount) were not passed to the controllers

Comment: It says : Livewire: [wire:model] is missing a value. on the console

Comment: In my solution I had to deduce some parts that you omitted in the question, so you have to adapt it to your situation: for example I didn't use any "wire:model", so it's strange that there is the error you mention. When you say *"contoller"* do you mean the Livewire component class? Can you modify the question by adding what is missing, i.e. your component class, the complete view (all the part around *<template x-for*) and maybe the component *<x-forms.input>* ?

Comment: Yes i mean the controller = livewire class
I already update my question

Comment: It seems to me that something is still missing: does it really only have that code in the class?
Can you post the rest of the view?

Comment: I forgot: the *input* component as you show it cannot work in this context, please confirm if it is the real component you use or if you have published an example component

Comment: that is the real component, so it can't be done using this solution ? Actually it can be done using theblivewire itself, however it should be avoided as it will always send a request to the BE whenever i click the add button

Comment: I've added in my answer a working version of your input component. I'm still waiting for your complete Livewire view...

Comment: thanks your solution worked as expected !